# Нужна помощь в кнопках поделиться

Tags: javascript, share, ya-share2

Подскажите пожалуйста, в коде кнопок соц. сетей от Яндекса,

как в data-description вставить переменную php $new["opisanie"];

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Немного уточните. У вас .html или .php файл выводимой страницы

Comment: у меня php страницы

Answer (score 0):

Всё очень легко делается:

```
<button data-desciption="<?=$new['opisanie']?>"></button>
```

`<?=$new['opisanie'] ?>` идентично `<? echo " $new['opisanie'] " ?>`

Comment: Извиняюсь. Если честно не понял.
Если добавляешь так <button data-desciption=" <?=$new["opisanie"]?> " 
   </button>
то не работает
Вторую строчку, где короткая запись не понял

Comment: изменил ответ, посмотрите надо использовать одинарные кавычки в получении элемента массива